# JQuery UI Autcomplete replaces Label with Value on select

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery UI Autocomplete with an ASP.NET Textbox to populate the label as well as the value. Here is where i map the data from an ajax call:

```
success: function (data) {
    response($.map(data, function (item) {
        return {
            label: item.label,
            value: item.value
        }
    }));
}
```

The label is the text, the value is a number used to identify that row. My problem is when the user selects an option, the textbox replaces the label with the value. So if they select 'John Smith', the textbox changes from 'John Smith' to '1234', etc. How can I manipulate the select event to leave the text in the textbox? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Here is a more complete view of my aspx page:

```
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txbSearchKeyword" runat="server" Columns="50" />
    </div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="selectedRecordId" runat="server" />
```

and the Jquery:

```
(function () {
    $("#txbSearchKeyword").autocomplete
    ({
        source:
            function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "AutoComplete.asmx/GetAutoCompleteList",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ keywordStartsWith: request.term }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.label,
                                value: item.value
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
        minLength: 2
    });

    $("#txbSearchKeyword").autocomplete
    ({
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#selectedRecordId').val(ui.item.value);
            DoSomethingwithdataAJAXfunction(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the jQuery and some HTML here? It is hard troubleshoot without seeing all of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps some of this snippet will help you:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    var hasValue = (ui.item.value != undefined && ui.item.value != "" && ui.item.value != null);
    if (hasValue) {
        var focusedElement = $(this);
        focusedElement.val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
},
focus: function(event, ui) {
    return false; // return "true" will put the value (label) from the selection in the field used to type
},
```

As an aside, I do not know why you have things separated when:

```
minLength: 2
 });
  $("#txbSearchKeyword").autocomplete
 ({ 
    select:...
```

could simply be:

```
minLength: 2,
select:...
```

Comment: exactly what i needed, thank you! I didn't know I could use the focus event in that way. And thanks for the other improvement as well!

Answer (score 0):

`value` is the variable that will be displayed in the textfield.

So you need to change it. `label: item.value, value: item.label` :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This does not help me however as the label is what is displayed in the AutoComplete suggestion list. So my dropdown would show all the ID numbers.

Answer (score 0):

im assuming that you want the item that is selected to appear in

```
ID="txbSearchKeyword"
```

this textbox ?

try adding this to your autocomplete:

```
({
    select: function (event, ui) {

     //add this -->  $('#txbSearchKeyword').val(ui.item.label);
       $('#selectedRecordId').val(ui.item.value);
        DoSomethingwithdataAJAXfunction(ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

the line you could try to add is in comments. i had the very same problem today and it worked for me.